# Why is this resource directive showing in the list of available forms?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I just stumbled on something very peculiar. Refer to this screenshot:

[image: Project Options > Forms]

Why is it showing `$R *.res` in the list of available forms? This project only has two forms and one additional unit, and here's the project's main file source:

```
program MyProgram;

uses
  Forms,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {fMain},
  uEmail in 'uEmail.pas' {frmEmail},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Other.Unit in 'Other.Unit.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Iceberg Classico');
  Application.Title := 'My Program Title';
  Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

PS - This is slightly modified code, the only thing that changed was the program name, program title, and the name of one of the units (`Other.Unit.pas`) which I know is a bad example since `Unit` is a reserved word. But the original unit name has a namespace prefix such as this one.

**UPDATE**

I followed the recommendation to move this RES reference to before the uses clause. After dong this (and cleaning all temp files, restarting IDE, etc.), it still shows in the list. But to my surprise, the IDE has actually added this RES reference back!

So now the IDE its self has turned it into:

```
UpdateUnit in 'UpdateUnit.pas' {$R *.res};
```

(UpdateUnit is a new name I gave it so I'm not giving internal information away)

So, I opened the DPROJ file and did a search for `*.res` and sure enough found this:

```
<ItemGroup>
        ....
        <DCCReference Include="UpdateUnit.pas">
            <Form>$R *.res</Form>
        </DCCReference>
```

Comment: At a very basic level, it looks like it is parsing "unitname" IN "filename" and then looking for the next comment for the form name. The question then is why is there that last file in the format of forms?

Comment: Modifying a main project source invites such kind of bugs. Unfortunately, there are no workarounds.

Comment: Well I've never modified this file, and I'm not looking for a fix or workaround - but an explanation as to why this happened.

Comment: Created QC report: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115964 and it looks like their Quality Control website needs some Quality Control of its own...

Comment: Isn't "unit" a reserved word?

Comment: Ahh I changed that in StackOverflow to not show our private naming, that's just sample text.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this, what Delphi version are you using? Have you tried changing to a different build configuration?

Comment: SO is the wrong place for this. You should create a concrete repro and submit a QC report.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge, I see "project owned units" has been reordered in your uses clause. IDE wants "library units" at the top, and "project units" at the bottom (and accompanied with `in` predicate).

Comment: What has likely happened is this; at some point you may have edited the .dpr file in a manner that confused the parser into thinking that "$R *.res" was the form name. You then saved it while in that state, which also injected that information into the .dproj file. The IDE tries to keep those two things in sync and sometimes will take the .dproj file as being the "master" and will update the .dpr file to match. You should be able to safely remove the <Form>$R *.res</Form> from the dproj file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As written, I could not reproduce this... however if I removed the trailing semicolon (";") after the "Other.Unit in 'Other.unit.pas'" line, the "$R *.res" shows up in the project options.

This isn't a bug, as far as I can see. Since your comments indicate that the presented code isn't the same as what you're using it will be hard to diagnose. I will try and explain what is happening; If you look at the uMain and uEmail units, there is a comment next to each that is the name of the form. Since these units may not actually be open in the IDE, there is no way to know if there is a form associated with that unit. The presence of a uMain.dfm isn't a guarantee that uMain.pas actually has a form (it may be left-over cruft). The IDE places this simple comment within the uses clause for that unit in order to tell the project manager that this unit has a form.

By removing the ";", the parser sees the next comment token as {$R *.res}. It then concludes that Other.Unit.pas must contain a form named "$R *.res". It does no validation of the name nor even tries to open the unit. It merely takes the raw content of that comment and assumes it's a form name.

You can safely move the {$R *.res} before the uses clause so that the project parser doesn't confuse that directive comment as a form.

EDIT: From my comment above:

What has likely happened is this; at some point you may have edited the .dpr file in a manner that confused the parser into thinking that "$R *.res" was the form name. You then saved it while in that state, which also injected that information into the .dproj file. The IDE tries to keep those two things in sync and sometimes will take the .dproj file as being the "master" and will update the .dpr file to match. You should be able to safely remove the $R *.res from the dproj file.

Comment: I came across this at a client last week. It wasn't a change in the .dpr that triggered it. Not sure how Delphi XE2 got confused though. Could trace it back in their version control system. Will list the changes in the .dpr and .dproj in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This does not reproduce with Delphi XE2 Update 4 (see below).
More accurately: the code you posted does not reproduce.

But the scenario that you describe in the comments does: if the `.dproj` is hosed, the IDE will re-add the incorrect information to your `.dpr`. See below for further explanation.

At the end of this answer an edit that shows you an occurrence at a client: Delphi XE2 can get confused somehow to the internal state gets wrong, and it writes back both a wrong `.dproj` and `.dpr` file.

If the code you posted is not the same as the code that fails, please correct your question with the code that fails (and post a comment to my answer so I get a notification and update the QC entry; in the current form your QC entry will be marked as "cannot reproduce" and then closed).

I have seen the IDE being confused in various places (including the project options) after an AV, or when line-endings in the .pas or .dpr files are not CRLF, or when manually editing .DPR files.

Those issues usually disappear when you restart the IDE. Sometimes you even have to clean up some files (with extensions like .DCU, .local, etc).

*Worst case is that the IDE got so confused that both the .DPR and .DPROJ contain wrong information (hence my comment), that appears to be the case in your situation (thanks to your edited question). You can manually edit the .DPROJ and .DPR files to resolve this. Make sure to have backups as it is easy to break the XML format of a .DPROJ file*

I could reproduce it if I moved the RES declaration before the semicolon: that's the format the IDE expects so it can parse the .DPR for Forms, DataModules and Frames (and potentially other design surfaces):

```
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {DataModule1: TDataModule},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Frame2: TFrame};
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {Form3};
```

Basically, you should not edit the .DPR file: the IDE owns it and will rewrite it for instance when you add new units to your project, you change the program icon, change the application caption, etc.

Main program that does not reproduce:

```
program MyProgram;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {fMain},
  uEMail in 'uEMail.pas' {frmEmail},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Other.Module in 'Other.Module.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Iceberg Classico');
  Application.Title := 'My Program Title';
  Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The options dialog:

[image]

Main program that does reproduce (note where the RES is):

```
program MyProgram;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {fMain},
  uEMail in 'uEMail.pas' {frmEmail},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Other.Module in 'Other.Module.pas' {$R *.res};

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Iceberg Classico');
  Application.Title := 'My Program Title';
  Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

*Edit 20130616*

Ran into this at a client below is the diff of the before/after in both the `.dpr` and the `.dproj` (some of the names have been anonymized).

Delphi XE2 got confused somehow: it was not an edit in the .dpr that induced this problem.

There are two things I suspect:

- an access violation somewhere overwrote some internal state causing the internal project structure to be damaged (the project depends on a lot of 3rd party packages to be installed, all of which are in the same BDS process)
- there is lots of code in the .dpr that might have confused the internal project structure

I've refactored all of the .dpr code into a separate module. Hopefully that was the cause and this won't happen again.

Old .dpr fragment:

```
program Server;

uses
  ShareMem,
  SysUtils,
  Forms,
  SvcMgr,
  WebReq,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {fMain},
//...
  uDBOrm in 'uDBOrm.pas',
  uWinProxySettings in '..\..\..\Server\trunk\Server\uWinProxySettings.pas',
  GpStuff in 'GpStuff.pas',
  DSiWin32 in 'DSiWin32.pas';

{$R *.res}

function IsServiceApp: Boolean;
begin
//...
end;

begin
  if IsServiceApp = True then
  begin
//...
  end else
  begin // GUI Interface
    if Assigned(Application) then
       FreeAndNil(Application);
    Forms.Application.Initialize;
    Forms.Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
    Forms.Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
    Forms.Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

New .dpr fragment:

```
program Server;

uses
  ShareMem,
  SysUtils,
  Forms,
  SvcMgr,
  WebReq,
  uMain in 'uMain.pas' {fMain},
//...
  uDBOrm in 'uDBOrm.pas' {$R *.res},
  uWinProxySettings in '..\..\..\Server\trunk\Server\uWinProxySettings.pas',
  GpStuff in 'GpStuff.pas',
  DSiWin32 in 'DSiWin32.pas';

{$R *.res}

function IsServiceApp: Boolean;
begin
//...
end;

begin
  if IsServiceApp = True then
  begin
//...
  end else
  begin // GUI Interface
    if Assigned(Application) then
       FreeAndNil(Application);
    Forms.Application.Initialize;
    Forms.Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
    Forms.Application.CreateForm(TfMain, fMain);
    Forms.Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

Old .dproj fragment:

```
        <DCCReference Include="uDBOrm.pas"/>
        <DCCReference Include="..\..\..\Server\trunk\Server\uWinProxySettings.pas"/>
```

New .dproj fragment:

```
        <DCCReference Include="uDBOrm.pas">
            <Form>$R *.res</Form>
        </DCCReference>
        <DCCReference Include="..\..\..\Server\trunk\Server\uWinProxySettings.pas"/>
```

Comment: I see. Oddly enough, I a) deleted all temp files (dcu, local, etc.), b) moved the RES to top of unit, c) recompiled, d) closed and re-opened IDE, and it's still there... Hmmm...

Comment: Please post the complete .DPR in your question. Maybe even the complete .DPROJ as well.

Comment: This is, but as I try to explain in my question, I changed the text so that I'm not telling the world the name of the software I'm working with.

Comment: HA! After moving the RES to the top of the unit, the IDE literally added it back to the end of the unit name!

Comment: thanks for the comment, I've added that scenario to the answer.